# can't use cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

i'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html).

I installed OpenCV 3.3.1.11, but when I checked which version is installed I found 4.1.2
I use spyder 3.6

but when I run it, I get this error

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'

I tried to uninstall anaconda and uninstall all OpenCv version but it didn't work

Comment: CMake options affect how the underlying tools are built. Did you try anything related to that, as the error suggests?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk it work in another laptop :/

Comment: @SavageHenry i thought it's about the version, because even if i reinstalled anaconda and install OpenCV 3.3.1, it remain 4.1.2,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked some of my conda environments. Looks like you can have more than 1 opencv installed at the same time.

Try writing this in Anaconda Promt (after activating your environment, if you have one): **conda list**.

Then compare it with your pip list by typing: **pip list**.

Do you see two different OpenCVs on one of the list?

If so, try deleting the one you don't need.

Or else, try downgrading the one which is being shown on the error.

Comment: thank you, i found two, i just delete one of them and it works now 
i'm very grateful